# An internal error occurred during: "Importing Maven projects" NoSuchMethod

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am unable to build my work space in eclipse and it gives me an internal error. The stack trace is

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2016-10-25 15:54:55.470
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Importing Maven projects".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.m2e.core.embedder.IMaven.getMojoParameterValue(Lorg/apache/maven/project/MavenProject;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/apache/maven/model/Plugin;Lorg/apache/maven/model/ConfigurationContainer;Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at com.basistech.m2e.code.quality.shared.AbstractMavenPluginConfigurationTranslator.getParameterValue(AbstractMavenPluginConfigurationTranslator.java:36)
    at com.basistech.m2e.code.quality.shared.AbstractMavenPluginConfigurationTranslator.getParameterValue(AbstractMavenPluginConfigurationTranslator.java:43)
    at com.basistech.m2e.code.quality.checkstyle.MavenPluginConfigurationTranslator.isSkip(MavenPluginConfigurationTranslator.java:95)
    at com.basistech.m2e.code.quality.checkstyle.EclipseCheckstyleProjectConfigurator.handleProjectConfigurationChange(EclipseCheckstyleProjectConfigurator.java:106)
    at com.basistech.m2e.code.quality.shared.AbstractMavenPluginProjectConfigurator.mavenProjectChanged(AbstractMavenPluginProjectConfigurator.java:181)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.mavenProjectChanged(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.notifyProjectChangeListeners(ProjectRegistryManager.java:732)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.applyMutableProjectRegistry(ProjectRegistryManager.java:855)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.configureNewMavenProject(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.importProjects(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.MavenImportWizard$1.doCreateMavenProjects(MavenImportWizard.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.AbstractCreateMavenProjectsOperation.run(AbstractCreateMavenProjectsOperation.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.MavenImportWizard$3.runInWorkspace(MavenImportWizard.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

I have tried re importing my project, deleting the .settings, .project files and folders and have also tried to start a new works pace but I still get the same problem.

Can anybody please help me out here?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This is always caused by importing some conflict dependencies. Post your

```
pom.xml
```

Comment: I am not entirely sure if I am allowed to post the pom.xml, but I am fairly certain that the pom is fine
1) It is working fine for others in the team
2) I reduced the pom to the minimum and still the same result
3) It seems to originate in a core eclipse class

I could however be wrong though

But yes I agree that it looks to be some sort of a (class?) conflict

Comment: Then check your maven plugin in eclipse ?  Maybe it's out of date ?